# Subarray in a CSV field and read it with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have the following CSV file, where the field called "phone_numbers" needs to be a subarray.

```
"username","first_name","last_name","phone_numbers","city","address"
"testuser","Test","Example",["+00 000 00 000","+01 000 00 000"],"New York","5th Example address"
```

and the following php function

```
function csv_to_array($filename, $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if(!$header) {
                $header = $row;
            } else {
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The actual output I get is:

```
PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

1. What should I change either in the csv file, field:
   `["+00 000 00 000","+01 000 00 000"]`
   or in the PHP function in order to have the following output?
2. Can I do the same changes for all the CSV fields, so each of them can eventually contain a subarray?

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [username] => testuser
    [first_name] => Test
    [last_name] => Example
    [phone_numbers] => Array
        (
            [0] => +00 000 00 000
            [1] => +01 000 00 000
        )

    [city] => New York
    [address] => 5th Example address
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you change the CSV entry to `"+00 000 00 000, +01 000 00 000"` and then `explode` with a `, `?

Comment: Many thanks for answering @verisimilitude. The problem with explode is that creates an array of every field, even when it has no comma inside.
`[username] => Array( [0] => testuser )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @verisimilitude, I got it right with explode and a couple of changes more.

Now the CSV looks like this:

```
"username","first_name","last_name","phone_numbers","city","address"
"testuser","Test","Example","+00 000 00 000, +01 000 00 000","New York","5th Example address"
```

And the PHP function:

```
function csv_to_array($filename, $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    $subarray_split = ',';
    $subarray_found = FALSE;

    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if(!$header) {
                $header = $row;
            } else {
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    $subarray_found = strpos($value, $subarray_split);
                    if ($subarray_found !== FALSE)
                        $row[$key] = array_map('trim', explode(',', $value));
                }
                unset($value);
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The output is as follow:

```
    [username] => testuser
    [first_name] => Test
    [last_name] => Example
    [phone_numbers] => Array
        (
            [0] => +00 000 00 000
            [1] => +01 000 00 000
        )

    [city] => New York
    [address] => 5th Example address
```

I haven't check how efficient this is, but did the job:

```
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    $subarray_found = strpos($value, $subarray_split);
                    if ($subarray_found !== FALSE)
                        $row[$key] = array_map('trim', explode(',', $value));
                }
```